# Which Debian Version For Intel Core2 Duo T5450 @ 1.67GHz CPU

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to install debian on my laptop. It had 3GB of RAM and an Intel Core2 Duo T5450 @ 1.67GHz CPU.
I would like to download the "netinst" version of the Debian installer from the link below but I'm unsure as to which version to download.
http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/
I think the choice is between [i386][ia64]...
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

64 Bit Definitely (AMD64)...

since your processor supports it: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=30787&processor=T5450&spec-codes=SLA4F

but be aware, not all applications work on the 64 bit distro... so make sure the application you need to use it for supports 64 bit or at least the 32 bit workaround...

Search for "Running 32-bit Applications on 64-bit Debian GNU/Linux" on debian-administration.org for more info or reference. 

(couldn't post more than a link since my rep. is still low... )

Answer (score 2):

AMD64 unless you have requirements that limit you to 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ia64 is completely different architecture and you can choose only between i386 and amd64.

Furthermore if you choose 64bit version over 32 you should remember that some software is distributed only in 32bit binary format. However running it is usually possible it could be problematic, for example you'll have to keep bot 32 and 64 bit libraries. For me Xilinx ISE WebPack was an app which made me switch back to 32 bit distributions.